# Multiprocessing pool map adds extra throughput time, how to reduce it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, latency, throughput

As I am working on low latency requirement, I tried to use multiprocessing pool, each process is running in parallel and in my example it takes 1 second. But the overall process is adding extra 300ms i.e., 1 second 300ms.

Why the extra time is added? Is there any better way to reduce this throughput?

I referred this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70785059/8353711) which is having max `2ms`(avg of `0.1ms`) of throughput, but not working for my code(i.e., fetch data from database using pandas read_sql)

I am assuming there will be a better way to reduce the extra overhead time.

**Code:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test_func(x):
    ts = time.time()
    time.sleep(1) # In my case `pd.read_sql(query, conn_str)` which takes around 300ms
    print(time.time() - ts)
    return x

ts = time.time()

num_process = mp.cpu_count()*2

with Pool(num_process) as pool:
    results = pool.map(test_func, [1, 2, 3])
    print("*********")
    print(time.time() - ts)


print("*********")
print(time.time() - ts)
```

**Output:**

```
1.0009253025054932 # each process taken time
1.0011048316955566
1.0010230541229248


*********
1.2178916931152344 # time taken inside pool context manager
*********
1.2484805583953857 # total time
```

Number of process available:

```
mp.cpu_count()*2 --> 32
```

Is it possible to bring the total time closer to 1 second? If yes, how?

Comment: @Cow I was going through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70785059/8353711) which is having `2ms` throughput, but it's taking very long time for my code( i.e., fetch data from database).

Comment: Your test is flawed. time.sleep() isn't very accurate. If you note the time before a 1 second sleep then note the duration you might expect the result to be 1 second. It won't be

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: @DarkKnight Got your point. `time.sleep` is for illustration purpose, my overall time should be closer to each process time and I have only 3 process which I assume running in parallel.

Comment: @Plagon I am using linux `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`

Comment: Given that your real processing is database related (i.e., not CPU bound) then you could consider multithreading rather than multiprocessing

Comment: @DarkKnight, Thanks, multithreading helped to reduce extra overhead from `300ms` to `10ms` (I am using `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`). Can you provide this as an answer and explain why multithreading is better in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, multiprocessing is better suited to CPU-intensive work whereas multithreading is better for I/O bound work.

That is a huge generalisation. What you actually need will depend on the various complexities of your code.

The concurrent.futures module has two very useful classes namely: ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor. Their attributes are identical meaning that you can easily swap from one to the other during development by simply changing the class name but without changing any other code.

Here's some code that gives you a framework for determining which is best suited to your needs. Just implement the do_work() function appropriately.

The code will execute the process() function NVALS times and provide you with an average duration for both multithreading and multiprocessing.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import perf_counter
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator
import os

NVALS = 10

if (CPU_COUNT := os.cpu_count()) is None or CPU_COUNT < 2:
    CPU_COUNT = 2

POOLSIZE = min((CPU_COUNT//2, NVALS))
DP = 8

def do_work(i: int, s:str) -> tuple[int, str]:
    print(i, s)
    return i, s

def process(t: tuple[int, str]) -> float:
    _start = perf_counter()
    do_work(*t)
    return perf_counter() - _start

def values(nvals: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, str]]:
    for i in range(nvals):
        yield i, 'a'
    
def main(executor: Callable):
    with executor(POOLSIZE) as _executor:
        print(executor.__name__)
        # create a list of tuples
        _sum = sum(_executor.map(process, values(NVALS)))
        print(f'Average={_sum/NVALS:.{DP}f}\n')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    for executor in ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor:
        main(executor)
```

Comment: How to pass arguments to `do_work` function? (In my case, I need to send query, connecting string) and how to collect the return values?

Comment: @Pythoncoder In this code you can see how values are passed to process() which could then be passed to do_work(). You can also see how the return values are acquired so I don't understand what else you could possibly need

Comment: If I replace `range(NVALS)` with `[(i, "a") for i in range(NVALS)]` and `process(x: int)` to `process(x: int, y: str)`, then I am getting `TypeError: process() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`. To pass multiple arguments, I think we need to a different way. For now, I am passing one argument to `process` and unpacking it inside function, which doesn't look clean.

Comment: @Pythoncoder I've enhanced the code to show how you can pass multiple arguments to the process() function